# Where to put array of data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, model-view-controller

I am trying to best follow MVC. Where is the 'correct' place to put my array of data? I am talking about the people array below. Should it be placed in the view controller below, or should it be part of a data service/data store class that is instantiated in the view controller (through dependency injection)? I have seen it done both places.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var people: [Person] = []

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }

        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Person> =  Person.fetchRequest()

        people = try? context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's totally fine to store it inside viewController according to MVC. Although, you can move it to some separate **source** object, or **dataProvider**, but most of the time it's ok, and from your code it seems for me as it's okay.

I have few comments for you:

1) It's better to move out CoreData logic from AppDelegate - whether to separate singleton, or to service object (preferably, cause singletons are hard to test)

2) **context.fetch** is better to wrap inside **do {} catch {}** block most of times

3) You don't have to wait until **viewWillAppear** fires to fetch your data, at least from provided code

4) It's better to move logic of fetching inside some service with method like **fetchPersons**

Comment: Thank you, can you please clarify comment 3? You mean fetch the data inside viewDidLoad?

Comment: exactly, **viewDidLoad** seams more appropriate place to do it, unless you want to refetch it each time view appears